# Use _replace method of namedtuple to update the fields of other data structures containing the nt

Tags: python

I am learning about namedtuple. I would like to find a way, using the `._replace` method, to update all the appearances of a `namedtuple` wherever they are.

Say I have a list of nodes, and lists of elements (two-node beams, four-node quads) and boundaries ("one node" elements) defined by these nodes.

I am playing around with doing this:

```
from collections import namedtuple as nt
Node = nt('Node', 'x y')
Beam = nt('Beam', 'i j')
Quad = nt('Quad', 'i j k l')
Boundary = nt('Boundary', 'b')
#Define some nodes:
n1 = Node(0,0)
n2 = Node(0,1)
n3 = Node(1,1)
n4 = Node(1,0)
#And some other things using those nodes:
q1 = Quad(n1,n2,n3,n4)
b1 = Boundary(n1)
be1 = Beam(n1,n4)
```

Now, if I replace `n1` with a new `Node`:

```
n1 = n1._replace(x=0.5,y=0.5)
print(n1)  # Node(x=0.5,y=0.5)
```

None of the other items are updated:

```
print(b1)  # Boundary(b=Node(x=0, y=0))
```

I understand the Python naming and object model and the *why* behind this: `b1.b` has been set to the *object* `Node(0,0)`, *not* the name `n1`. So when `n1` is changed, the other namedtuples still contain the same object as before, while `n1` gets a new object.

What I would like to do is change this behavior so that when I change `n1`, the changes are "felt" in `b1`, `be1`, `q1`, etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All instances of `namedtuple`-produced classes are *immutable*. `._replace()` creates a *new* instance, it doesn't even update the one instance you call this on.

Because the instances are immutable you cannot do what you want with a `namedtuple`. You'll have to provide such functionality in a subclass, effectively breaking the immutability. Or just provide your own `Node` custom class that allows the attributes to be mutated directly:

```
class Node(object):
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y')

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0.__class__.__name__}({0.x!r}, {0.y!r})'.format(self)
```

Like a `namedtuple`, this class uses [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to cut back on memory use. You can set the `x` and `y` attributes directly on instances, and any other references to the instance will see the change:

```
>>> class Node(object):
...     __slots__ = ('x', 'y')
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '{0.__class__.__name__}({0.x!r}, {0.y!r})'.format(self)
... 
>>> n1 = Node(10, 20)
>>> n2 = n1
>>> n2
Node(10, 20)
>>> n1.x = 42
>>> n1.y = 81
>>> n2
Node(42, 81)
```

Comment: This is bad news! Do you think I should subclass namedtuple, or do something else entirely?

Comment: @RickTeachey: creating your own class is easy enough.

Comment: Yeah I know *how* to make my own, I'm just *very bad* at it. I get bogged down in trying to predict everything I'm going to need to avoid having to go back and change it later.

Comment: I know what `__repr__` is for.  What is `'{0.__name__}({0.x!r}, {0.y!r})'.format(self)` doing? Is that a regular expression or something?

Comment: @RickTeachey: it is a [formatted string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings); the `str.format()` method drives it.

Comment: @RickTeachey: I pass `self` to `str.format()` as a positional argument, the format string accesses that as `0`. `0.x` then is the `x` attribute on `self`, and `0.__class__.__name__` is the current class name. `!r` forces a `repr()` call so you always get a nice Python representation of the attribute values.

Comment: Gotcha. Instead of writing all those classes (there are others I didn't mention), what about making one parent class that accepts a tuple argument defining the slots? Then I can just say `Node = MyFancyTupleClass('x','y')`, `n1 = Node(0,0)`, etc?

Comment: @RickTeachey: you'll need to define `__slots__` at the class level; this is what the `namedtuple()` class factory does too. You could write your own, generating a class on the fly is not that hard (just produce a `class` statement in a function).

Comment: Any suggestions on videos or reading about generating classes this way in Python?

Comment: @RickTeachey: this one is very comprehensive: [What is a metaclass in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949)

Answer (score 2):

4 and 1/2 years later: If I were doing this today, I'd probably reach for the [`dataclasses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) first:

```py
from dataclasses import make_dataclass as md

Node = md('Node', 'x y')
Beam = md('Beam', 'i j')
Quad = md('Quad', 'i j k l')
Boundary = md('Boundary', 'b')
```

...and since these objects are mutable (unlike `namedtuple`), instead of replacing a node with a new instance, we can simply update the node position:

```py
n1.x = 0.5
n1.y = 0.5
print(n1)  # Node(x=0.5,y=0.5)
```

This solves the problem entirely.